# Simulate chrome selected input style

Tags: css, google-chrome, styles, outline

Can someone tell me the css that produces in all browsers the selected yellow outline style that chrome is using ?
Thank you.

Comment: Or you can just inspect the element's CSS rules in the user-agent stylesheet using Chrome's DOM Inspector tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out Twitter Bootsrap's [Form](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms) component, they are using a blue glow.